# Проблема с подключением к БД Mysql с эмулятора андроид c# maui

Tags: c#, mysql, maui

Возникла интересная проблема:
При запуске приложения на *Windows Machine* подключение к локальной БД *MySql* и последующий поиск данных выполняется успешно (простая форма авторизации).
Но при развёртывании приложения на эмуляторе *Android* (Эмулятор закачан через *Visual Studio, Pixel 7 Pro, API 31 Android 12*) возникают следующие ошибки:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.'

*Нажимаю "Продолжить"*:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.'

*Нажимаю ещё раз, вылезает ошибка сверху, потом ещё раз нажимаю, и заканчивается отладка.*

**С Windows подобных проблем нету.**

Мой код:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace UCLTest
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    DB db = new DB();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void nameEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var username = nameEntry.Text;
    }

    void nameEntry_TextChanged2(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var password = nameEntry2.Text;
    }

    async void LoginButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var username = nameEntry.Text;
        var password = nameEntry2.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Пожалуйста, введите логин и пароль", "OK");
            return;
        }

        db.openConnection();

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM newuserstable WHERE userlogin = @userL AND userpassword = @userP", db.getConnection());
        command.Parameters.Add("@userL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
        command.Parameters.Add("@userP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Успех", "Вы авторизовались!", "OK");
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Неверный логин или пароль", "OK");
        }
        db.closeConnection();
    }
}

}
```

**Это подключение к базе данных:**

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UCLTest
{
class DB
{

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection($"server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=ucl"); 

    public void openConnection() => connection.Open();

    public void closeConnection() => connection.Close();

    public MySqlConnection getConnection() => connection;

}
}
```

*P.s, на табуляцию не обращайте внимание, впервые пишу тут, в коде всё нормально.*
Никаких других скриптов с кодом в проекте нету. Установлен только один `Nuget` пакет *MySql.Data*

Заранее благодарю всех за уделённое время и возможную помощь!

Comment: Ошибку покажите целиком, ибо сейчас вы показали только "Инициализатор типа для 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' выбросил исключение", то есть заголовок, а не саму ошибку. Пока я лично вижу `localhost` соединение, то есть соединение только с данного устройства, а вы вдруг пытаетесь подключиться через него на андройде.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Как именно я могу отобразить ошибку? В разделе варнингов и ошибок она не отображается. Могу лишь сказать, что ссылается на connection.Open()
Такое чувство, что проблема в коннтекте к БД

Comment: Ну вы где-то получаете то, что в вопросе, вот там наверно и ищите более подробный лог, более подробное описание. В любом случае, мои замечания про `localhost` это не отменяет.

Comment: Насчёт того, что подключение локальное. Это да, оно локальное.
Но опять же, я пытаюсь подключиться к БД с эмулятора, который запускает сама Visual Studio.
Получается, эмулятор работает на этом же ПК, где запущен SQL сервер. И они оба соответственно в одной сети.
Я конечно пробовал изменить localhost на IP с сайта 2.ip, но проблема не решилась.
Единственное не пробовал юзать IP ПК в локальной сети, то есть 192.160.0.164

Comment: Любой эмулятор - это создание **новой** виртуальной сети, расценивайте эмулятор как отдельное, не связанное с вашим компьютером устройство.

Comment: То есть мне попробовать подключиться через IP пк в локалке? То  есть: 192.160.0.164

Comment: Скажу так, ни кто не использует базу данных вот так как вы на клиентских приложениях, ибо это не безопасно. Вы даете клиенту прямой доступ к базе, когда должны ее скрывать, делая "прослойку" в виде, допустим, API сайта, который будет авторизировать клиента и его запросы передавать базе. Также, если ваше приложение всеж будет работать с базой через интернет, то там должен быть указан **внешний IP адрес вашего устройства**, а не ваша локальная сеть. Ну, если вы хотите использовать локальную сеть, то изучайте спецификацию эмулятора, смотрите проброс адресов, повторю, сейчас вы в двух разных сетях

Comment: Ошибся, вместо 160 - 168. Попробовал заменить localhost на это, не вышло. Кстати, для включение БД использую MAMP PRO 5

Comment: Я попробовал использовать внешний IP, взятый с 2ip.ru, но проблема та же. Единственный вариант, который остаётся для отладки на андроиде - купить хостинг базы данных, и выполнять коннект к ней. Насчёт того, что использовать API сайта и т.д. - это понятно, я буду использовать этот метод в дальнейшем, сейчас просто пытаюсь написать приложение и тестировать локально.

Comment: `взятый с 2ip.ru` - внешний IP покупается у провайдера, это платная услуга. После покупки провайдер вам выдает постоянный IP и дает доступ к нему за NAT. Если у вас этого нет, то и к базе вы не подключитесь за пределами своей локальной сети. Ну а эмулятор, еще раз повторю, любая виртуализация обычно создает отдельную, виртуальную сеть, в которой сидит данное виртуальное устройство. Чтоб получить доступ за пределами этой сети, эмулятор надо настраивать, у всех это по разному, ищите.

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю вас за ответы и развёрнутую информацию!
 Для теста попробую поискать самые дешёвые хостинги баз данных, попробую развернуть БД там, чисто для того, чтобы тестировать приложение у себя на эмуляторе, надеюсь, он сможет подключиться к БД (YouTube Он запускает нормально) Если всё дойдёт до релиза - там уж понятно, полноценный хостинг и защита от внешнего вмешательства.

Comment: Странное решение, но дело ваше. Я бы на вашем месте начал с изучение ошибки, которая должна точно сказать что не так. Не можете так посмотреть, ну оберните в `try/catch` и выведите на экран или запишите в файл, будет наглядно показано что не так. Потом, получив скорей всего ошибку о том, что невозможно подключиться к `localhost`, я бы пошел смотреть в какой всеж сети эмулятор, к чему он имеет доступ, понял бы, что он в своей виртуальной сети. После, пошел бы смотреть как получить доступ к основному компьютеру из эмулятора, получил бы, задал его IP. Но проще конечно купить сервер..)

Comment: Скорее всего проблема именно в коннекте. Так как я пытался с двух разных телефонов открыть в браузере localhost/phpMyAdmin - и ничего не получалось, а на ПК открывается панелька phpMyAdmin. Так же пытался в адресной строке браузеров на телефоне открыть это, используя 192.168.0.104 - тоже ничего не вышло. Пойду гуглить как взаимодействовать устройствам друг с другом по локалке, как найду решение - отпишусь.

Comment: В общем, нашёл бесплатный хостинг MySql
Через эмуляцию с ПК - удалось подключиться к БД
Я попробовал через отладку по USB запустить приложение на Samsung A21s, оно запустилось.
При попытке входа - приложение вылетает, исключения те-же самые.
К сожалению, я так и не понял как получить больше сведений касательно исключений.
Подскажите, как я могу записать исключения в файл?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось в выводе увидеть это:

```
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Security.Permissions.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ucltest/files/.__override__/System.Security.Permissions.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly 
System.Collections.Specialized.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ucltest/files/.__override__/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.ucltest/files/.__override__/System.Collections.Specialized.dll [External]
**System.TypeInitializationException:** 'The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.'
```

Проблему удалось решить. Вместо `MySql.Data` используйте `MySqlConnector`.